# Relation between 4 tables Data base of past papers

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am creating a relation between 4 tables in a db :

**class** : c_id // 9,10,11,12 pk 

**year** : y_id // 2017,2016,2015 pk 

**subject** : s_name // pk 

**subject_year** : r_id // pk 
s_name // fk 
y_id // fk 

**image** : img_id // pk 
img_title var 
img_url var 
r_id // fk

I want the subject name with the particular year when i insert an image .
relations between tables are correct or not ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should create a relationship table for class + year.

**class:**

- class_id // pk

**year:**

- year_id // pk

**class_year:**

- cy_id // pk
- class_id // fk
- year_id // fk

**subject:**

- sub_id // pk
- cy_id // fk
- sub_name

**Image:**

- img_id // pk
- sub_id // fk
- img_title
- img_url

Comment: this one also have a problem

Comment: it has a repetition ...... class 9 only have only one 2017 one 2016 2015.. not twice...but there is a class which has 2017 twice

Comment: With the same subject? Using table subject you can have many of them for each composition of class + year.